# Is it possible read delta table with dbt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, delta-lake, dbt

I used dbt (Spark adapter) on a cluster emr on AWS and when I used a table I had to connect to AWS datacatalog. Is there a way to read and use a table written on S3 and use it in the dbt queries?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Can you explain more what you've tried, and what errors you are encountering? (See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) You may be interested in the `dbt-external-tables` package.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because i don't know how to do and if it possible. I have just run dbt and use the tables with awsdatacatalog. I'll try with dbt-external-tables. Thank you.